# I want to disable the delete post button inside in post foreach blade.. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to disable the delete post button  inside  in post foreach blade laravel . where post has created_at in database , i want the " delete post button" get disable after 15 days
i tried with some javascript tutorials but i couldn't achieve that thing

Can anyone please help me.it would be much appreciated if you could help me
thanks in adavance

```
 <table id="" class="table ">


                <thead>

                <tr class="data-item master">  
               
                  <th>Name</th>                    
                  <th>post</th>                     
                 <th>about</th>
                 <th>image</th>
                 <th>Delete</th>

                </tr>

                </thead>
            <tbody>

       @foreach($data as $d)

         <tr>
      
        <td>{{$d->name}}</td>            
          <td>{{$d->postbody}}</td>              
           <td>{{$d->about}}</td>
             <td>{{url($d->image)}}</td>;

              <td><a href="{{ URL::to('edit/product/'.$d->id) }} "
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="edit">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit">edit post</i></a>
                 </td>

               <td><a href="{{ URL::to('delete/product/'.$d->id) }} "
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>delete post</a>
                 </td>  
           </tr>
       @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: show your code, its very easy with php

Comment: Thanks for showing interest Moshiur. I am showing codes

Comment: see my answer, I have added the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not disable an anchor tag but you can change the URL to # as dummy url

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->addDays(15) < \Carbon\Carbon::now())
    <a href="#"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="delete">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>delete post</a>
@else
    <a href="{{ URL::to('delete/product/'.$d->id) }}"
       class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="delete">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>delete post</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks Bro you save my day I was struggling since yesterday trying to do that with the  help of JavaScript but couldn't do that : Thanks Bro :)

Comment: you can also do it by php ternary operator , I just shared concept how to do

Answer (score 0):

It's simple use and conditional statement on the disable attribute.
Something like This

```
<button class="anyClass" {{ Carbon::addDays(15)->greaterThan($post->created_at) ? 'disable' : ' }}>Delete</button>
```

I think something like this will work

Comment: i couldn't get it  properly can you please show in details properly how to do that

Comment: It's simple  you have to add a ternary  condition  on disable  attribute so, that you can use it functional